# How to initialize all elements of a two-dimensional array to a particular value?

Tags: c++, c++14

Is there is any function similar to `memset()` to initialize all elements of a two-dimensional array to a certain value? `memset` can only be used to initialize the values to `0` and `-1`.

Comment: How about [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)?

Comment: "Since memset can be used to initialize the value only to 0 and -1" - Where did you get that from? `memset()` can set something to `42`, or any other value, just fine. But `std::fill` is probably still what you want.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That's partially true.  `memset` converts the value passed to an `unsigned char` so only those values can be used.  You couldn't intialize an integer array to `INT_MAX` for example (unless `INT_MAX == SCHAR_MAX`)

Comment: Well, I prefer using a vector of vector to store values as it's initialization is quite easy : `std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(M, std::vector<int>(N, C)); // declares a MxN matrix filled with C`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::fill`:

```
for(auto &arr : two_dim)
    std::fill(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), value);
```

This will work for many arrays and containers, like `std::vector`, `std::array`, and C arrays.

Also note that you can use `memset` to initialize all elements of an array to values other than `-1` and `0`. It's just that all the bytes in each element will have the same value, like `0x12121212`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is **fill()** function to initialize 2D array with certain value

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int a[row][column], value;
std::fill(a[0], a[0] + row * column, value);
```